# scan for heart rate peripherals not working with iOS8 and connected device

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am using the following code to connect to a bluetooth heart rate sensor. That worked fine until iOS8 and a connected bluetooth device under settings. When I press "Forget This Device" my code works again. How to modify the code to connect to a "connected heart rate sensor?"

// Request CBCentralManager to scan for heart rate peripherals using service UUID 0x180D
- (void) startScan
{

```
[self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]]
                                     options:nil];


for (CBPeripheral *peripheral in self.heartRateMonitors) {
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        NSUInteger serviceIdx = [peripheral.services indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(CBService *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [obj.UUID isEqual:@"180D"];
        }];

        if (serviceIdx == NSNotFound) {
            [peripheral discoverServices:@[@"180D"]];
            continue;
        }

        // have we discoverd the Heart Rate Measurement Characteristic?
        CBService *service = peripheral.services[serviceIdx];
        NSUInteger charIdx = [service.characteristics indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(CBCharacteristic *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [obj.UUID isEqual:@"180D"];
        }];

        if (charIdx == NSNotFound) {
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[@"180D"] forService:service];
            continue;
        }

        // Are we subscribed?
        CBCharacteristic *characteristic = service.characteristics[charIdx];
        if (!characteristic.isNotifying) {
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't there a reported problem in IOS8 about this?!

Comment: Some apps at the app store like Runtastic can handle it under iOS8. That means there must be a workaround!